# JAVA NIO ZIP FileSystem equivalent to ZipOutputStream setLevel

Tags: java, jar, compression, zip, nio

is there a ZipOutputStream setLevel(9) equivalent in JAVA NIOs ZIP FileSystem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) gives an example of how to use the Zip File System Provider:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");
        // locate file system by using the syntax 
        // defined in java.net.JarURLConnection
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");

        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
            Path externalTxtFile = Paths.get("/codeSamples/zipfs/SomeTextFile.txt");
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/SomeTextFile.txt");          
            // copy a file into the zip file
            Files.copy( externalTxtFile,pathInZipfile, 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an `Map<String, String>` environment variable used to set the zip properties. But for now, as defined in this [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemproviderprops.html), there is only two options: `create` to define if a new zip file should be created if it does not exist, and `encoding` to define the encoding scheme.